# Upgrading prototypejs 1.5 to 1.7 throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Guys I upgraded prototypejs from 1.5 to 1.7 but for some reason it is unable to read httpcurrent context attributes

In prototypejs 1.7 for some reason `getRequestAttribute` is failing to retrieve the parameter, which is not the case in 1.5

```
final HttpExecutionContext context = (HttpExecutionContext)ExecutionContext.getCurrentContext();
    final String selectedEntityId = (String)context.getRequestAttribute("id");
```

Has anyone faced any such issues?

Prototype 1.5

> message={"actions":[{"controller":"view","action":"show","params":{"layout":"version","params":{"id":"id","layout":"version"},"motif":"ContentSearch","title":"base","description":"version","views":[{"page":"sidebarSearch,sidebarMRU,sidebarRecycle","container":"container_sidebar","cache":"lazy","spin":false},{"page":"common/pageHeader","container":"container_pageHeader","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":false,"checkForGlobalHeader":true},{"page":"common/pageFooter","container":"container_pageFooter","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":true},{"page":"common/help","container":"container_pageHelp","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":false},{"page":"documentView","container":"container_content"}]}}]}&format=json&_=

Prototype 1.7

> message={"actions":[{"controller":"view","action":"show","params":{"layout":"version","params":{"__properties":["each","eachSlice","all","every","any","some","collect","map","detect","findAll","select","filter","grep","include","member","inGroupsOf","inject","invoke","max","min","partition","pluck","reject","sortBy","toArray","entries","zip","size","inspect","find","initialize","_each","set","get","unset","toObject","toTemplateReplacements","keys","values","index","merge","update","toQueryString","toJSON","clone","remove","_object","__properties","id"],"_object":{"id":"id"}},"motif":"ContentSearch","title":"base","description":"version","views":[{"page":"sidebarSearch,sidebarMRU,sidebarRecycle","container":"container_sidebar","cache":"lazy","spin":false},{"page":"common/pageHeader","container":"container_pageHeader","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":false,"checkForGlobalHeader":true},{"page":"common/pageFooter","container":"container_pageFooter","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":true},{"page":"common/help","container":"container_pageHelp","spin":false,"cache":"lazy","executeBodyOnLoad":false},{"page":"documentView","container":"container_content"}]}}]}&format=json

I am seeing `__properties` and `__object` node getting added in the newer version. What is the significance of them in the post request?

Comment: the only method in PrototypeJS that refers to attributes is [Element#readAttribute](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/readAttribute/) is that what you are attempting to use?

Comment: The issue is I am seeing the POST body is changing after I upgrade to a newer version. Updating the content of the main post with the difference

Comment: to be honest that looks like the entire javascript object is being encoded as JSON and sent to whatever backend script you have. `__properties` and `__object` are typically named that way by devs to indicate pseudo private object members. That being said those properties are not directly added by PrototypeJS code. If you can provide more context, etc and if needed open an issue we might be able to get to the bottom of it.